# Pygame side scroller isn't running as expected

Tags: python, pygame

I am planning on making a simple side-scroller game using pygame, but the scrolling part is tripping me up a bit. I loosely followed a YouTube tutorial to help me along the way, but the code I made isn't running as expected. I am running python 3.6 and am using PyCharm.

I have gone through the parts of the tutorial I have used and everything I have matches up correctly. The tutorial was using python 2.7 but I don't think it should effect it too much. I am relatively new to programming and python so I can't really tell what's wrong

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

black = (0, 0, 0, 255)
white = (255, 255, 255, 255)

w = 1280
h = 720
hw = w / 2
hh = h / 2

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
ds = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
pygame.display.set_caption("Side Scroller!")
FPS = 500

bg = pygame.image.load("mountains.png").convert()
bg_width, bg_height = bg.get_rect().size

stageWidth = bg_width * 2
stagePosX = 0

startScrollingPosX = hw

circleRadius = 25
circlePosX = circleRadius

playerPosX = circleRadius
playerPosY = 585
PlayerVelocityX = 0

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    k = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if k[K_RIGHT]: 
        playerVelocityX = 1
    elif k[K_LEFT]: 
        playerVelocityX = -1
    else: 
        playerVelocityX = 0

    playerPosX += playerVelocityX

    if playerPosX > stageWidth - circleRadius:
        playerPosX = stageWidth - circleRadius

    if playerPosX < circleRadius: 
        playerPosX = circleRadius
    if playerPosX < startScrollingPosX: 
        circlePosX = playerPosX
    elif playerPosX > stageWidth - startScrollingPosX: 
        circlePosX =  playerPosX - stageWidth + w
    else:
        circlePosX = startScrollingPosX
        stagePosX += -playerVelocityX

    rel_x = stagePosX % bg_width
    ds.blit(bg, (rel_x, 0))
    if rel_x < w:
        ds.blit(bg, (rel_x, 0))

    pygame.draw.circle(ds, white, (circlePosX, playerPosY - 25), 
    circleRadius, 0)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    ds.fill(black)
```

The background is supposed to start scrolling once the ball reaches the middle of the screen, but instead, it crashes once the ball hits the middle of the screen. Also, the background isn't being displayed fully, and the background is being cut off in the y direction.

Answer (score 1):

For the future, you should post what the terminal tells you when it crashes, there is a lot of information in there.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 69, in <module>
pygame.draw.circle(ds, white, (circlePosX, playerPosY - 25), circleRadius, 0)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

tells us there is an error in file "test.py" (what I called the file on my computer) on line 69,

it then shows us the line with the error

```
pygame.draw.circle(ds, white, (circlePosX, playerPosY - 25), circleRadius, 0)
```

and that it expected an integer, but instead got a float.

when the white ball reaches the middle, circlePosX is no longer an int (eg 67) but becomes a float (eg 44.5).

a 'solution' is:

```
pygame.draw.circle(ds, white, (int(circlePosX), playerPosY - 25), circleRadius, 0)
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! I appreciate the help and Ill be sure to include error messages in future posts